# How to read pre-defined values from a csv file and replace them with the variables in the "Text to send" field in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

**To achieve**:- To send the below-mentioned string to a server every 10 secs.

**Text to Send**:- '''XXXXXXX,XXXXXXX,XXXXXXXX,${packettype},${msgid},${pcktsts},${__threadGroupName},TSXXTSXXXX,${gpsfix},31082022,${__groovy(new Date().format("HHmmss", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')),)},${lat},${latdir},${long},${longdir},${speed},${head},${sat},${alt},${pdop},${hdop},${network},${ignsts},${mpsts},${mivolt},${ibvoltusg},${emsts},${tampalt},31,404,86,7b73,b74a,86,02a2,7b73,49,4d0a,7d0b,49,1948,7b73,59,Ffff,0000,100000,001,${frame},0.0,0.0,${ddist},()*${checksum}'''

Here in the above text, I want the variables to be replaced automatically on every request with the data pre-defined (against that particular variable) in a CSV file.

**Note**:- I want to send the above data/string through a TCP Sampler.
Suggestions are appreciated if someone could suggest a better way of achieving the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable from the CSV file which contains references to other [JMeter Variables or functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) you need to wrap it into [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval)

For example:

1. You have `foo` variable with the value of `bar`
2. You have entry in the CSV file which looks like `${foo}`
3. You defined `some-variable` in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) which returns this `${foo}` entry from the file

then:

- `${some-variable}` will return `${foo}`
- and `${__eval(${some-variable})}` will return `bar`

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)